# Moving the cursor in excel to next cell with different content

Tags: excel, cursor-position

Is there a shortcut for moving down a column or across a row to the next cell with a different value from the current one?

Comment: Use the Excel tag only for questions which involve programming directly. If you seek general help regarding Microsoft Excel which is not about programming then consider asking your question at SuperUser.com.

Comment: There won't be a built in shortcut no, but you'll be able to create a macro to do it. Do you want to move the mouse or just change the active cell?

Comment: over at Superuser there is a similar question, maybe that answer will help you http://superuser.com/a/873277/584622
(it did not work for me since I have a different keyboard layout and I can't seem to make it work for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for moving to the right until a different value is found.  Assign a shortcut key to this little macro:

```
Sub MoveToTheRight()
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    v = ActiveCell.Value
    j = ActiveCell.Column
    k = ActiveCell.Row
    For i = j + 1 To Columns.Count
        With Cells(k, i)
        If .Value <> v Then
            .Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

and here is a sample for moving downwards:

```
Sub MoveDown()
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    v = ActiveCell.Value
    j = ActiveCell.Column
    k = ActiveCell.Row
    For i = k + 1 To Rows.Count
        With Cells(i, j)
        If .Value <> v Then
            .Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```